# PHP glob() breaks on WordPress sub pages

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, cycle, glob

I've been struggling with this for a while now.

I've got an image gallery running using jQuery cycle plugin and the files are pulled from a folder using PHP glob(). Problem is, when I navigate to another page the gallery breaks due to the url of the new page being tacked on at the beginning of the file path.

Example:

Front Page url: `http://localhost/project/image-display-images/image.jpg`

Other Page url: `http://localhost/**NEWPAGE**/project/image-display-images/image.jpg`

Here's my code:

```
$files = glob('image-display-images/*.*');

       for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)

       {
          $num = $files[$i];
          echo '<img src="'.$num.'"'.' alt="Campus Images" width="362" height="246"/>';
       }
```

This would generate a list of images for jQuery cycle to scroll through. It only works on the front page though.

Any ideas?

SOLVED!

Here is my new code:

```
$files = glob(ABSPATH.'/image-display-images/*.*');

foreach ($files as $f) {
    echo '<image src="'.home_url(str_replace(ABSPATH,'',$f)).'"alt="Campus Images" width="362" height="246"/>';

}
```

This works on all pages.

Thank you!

Comment: If the image--display-images is a unique folder for all posts, try to pass the absolute path to the glob function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an absolute path:

```
$files = glob(ABSPATH.'image-display-images/*.*');
```

The WordPress Core sets the `ABSPATH` constant so it should be fairly reliable.

`glob` deals with filesystem paths, but you are trying to load URLs. To display the files the way you are trying to, you will need to convert the results to URLs. Here is a bare-bones example.

```
$files = glob(ABSPATH."*.*");
foreach ($files as $f) {
  echo home_url(str_replace(ABSPATH,'',$f));
}
```

You may better off writing you own function to grab your file names, rather than depending on `glob` which does come with a warning about not being available on some systems. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API

Comment: This actually gave me the correct paths on both pages but the images don't display.  This is the closest I've come to getting this to work properly. 

`$files = glob(ABSPATH.'image-display-images/*.*');`

CORRECTION: Its tacking on the page url to the image links, although its displaying as the proper link. 

Seems that I need to somehow remove the addition of the page url to the image links. hmm..

Comment: See my edit. Also, Don't use relative URLs in WordPress. They are a source of constant pain. Always create a complete path.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and see what I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Define the full path of your gallery instead of `'image-display-images/*.*'`
For example `glob('/var/etc/www/image-display-images/*.*')`

Comment: I've tried this one, but with no positive results. This causes nothing to show up at all.